# angular2 route guards validations

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating a new app using angular and I want to set up some validations on route guards. For example my url is: `localhost:4200/#/products` and if I want to navigate from the menu to other page of my app `localhost:4200/#/invoice` I don't want that to be possible the navigation just manually modifying the url and typing `invoice` instead of `products` but only on menu click.

so this is my guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core' ;
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AlwaysAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
        canActivate() {
          console.log('AlwaysAuthGuard');
          return true;
        }
      }
```

and this is the routing service:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: AppLoginComponent, data: { title: 'Login' }},
  { path: 'invoice', component: InvoiceComponent, canActivate: [AlwaysAuthGuard], data: { title: 'Invoice' }},
  { path: 'products', component: ProductsComponent, data: { title: 'Products' }},
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent, data: { title: 'Logout' }},
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, data: { title: 'Page Not Found' }}
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash : true });
```

So how can I add some validations on which I restrict the url modification and allow user to navigate to other pages only from navigation menu when is pressing on click.

Comment: The first question to ask is **why** ? Do you need a parameter or something ?

Comment: @trichetriche I need this because sometime the user should follow as flow but also if the user modifies url and he fill a form in a page, I cannot save or cancel that form so to avoid that I would like to restrict url modifications.

Comment: Well then, if accessing this page depends on variables, you could state that there are required variables to access to page, and if they're not present, then you redirect to the previous page.

Comment: @trichetriche you can add an example and post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store some flag on menu click. example:

listen for click event on your menu link and then do the following:

```
localstorage.setItem('menu-clicked', 'true');
```

and then in your 'AlwaysAuthGuard' check if 'menu-clicked' is available in localstorage or not. example:

```
canActivate() {
   // console.log('AlwaysAuthGuard');
   if(localstorage.getItem('menu-clicked') == 'true'){
      localstorage.removeItem('menu-clicked');
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```